# How to use a string and/or integers as variable name

Tags: ruby

I am writing an app using Plivo to send/receive text messages.

When a new user starts using the app, I'd like to use their phone number as a variable name, prepended with a generic letter. For example, `d13104325253 = myAppClass.new`

What is the best way to concatenate a string ("d") and a number (13104325253) and use them as a variable name?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @Jordan I don't need actual usernames, just phone numbers. preferably I would like to use incoming sms params as a call to Class functions on the instance, for example `params[:Text].response_handler()` instead of having to use a hash or db entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With dynamic keys it makes more sense to use a [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html) to store values:

```
d = {}
d[13104325253] = myAppClass.new
```

Dynamically generated local variables are not very user-friendly, because you would need to store the variable name in an other variable to be able to read it later. Whereas a hash at least allows to return all stored keys or search keys by a certain pattern.

Comment: I think this would work well for my purposes as I could use `d[params[:Text]]` when sms messages come in to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to concatenate a string ("d") and a number (13104325253)

Interpolation is.

```
"d#{13104325253}"
```

> and use them as a variable name?

There is no good way to do that. That is a bad thing to do. A bad thing to do, if you insist, is to use a binding object.

```
b = binding
b.local_variable_set("d#{13104325253}", myAppClass.new)
```

Comment: I agree with you, binding is a bad idea. Thanks for the answer even though it is not recommended.